# Why did images on WordPress posts get removed?

Tags: wordpress, image, post

I used to copy and paste online articles to my WordPress posts. I copied everything including images to my posts and then published it. However recently, when I looked back to my posts, some posts have lost their images. It says

```
 "No Alt text provided for this images"
```

At the place where the images are supposed to be. However, the images are still in the article.

My Co-worker said it happened after I installed "wp responsive recent post slider plugin", but not sure about it.

What can be possibly causing this issue?

I can manually go back to posts and copy and paste the original images to the posts, it works fine. However, I want to know why it happens so that I can prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied the HTML code from other websites, you most likely copied the `img` tags together with their original `src` attribute, meaning that your website loaded the images from the original website where you copied it from - the image file/s themselves never made it to your website.

So if these images are removed from the original website, or if simply their original URL was changed for some reason (for example a different folder structure), your website won't find the images anymore.

To check for that, check in your Wordpress media library if those images are in there. If no - see above. If yes, check the `src` attribute in the code and/or replace those not-working image tags with images from your media library.